# jQuery and jsTree - select child nodes by class

Tags: jquery, tree, jstree, nodes

Having difficulty checking (checkbox) all nodes by a specific class

here is what i have so far, i'm trying to check all the nodes that have the class checkMe

```
$('.MyTree').jstree('check_node', 'li.checkMe');
```

Unfortunately it doesnt work :)

I can only seem to check or unchecl all the nodes by doing

```
$('.MyTree').jstree('check_all'); //or uncheck_all
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: $('.MyTree li.checkMe input[type=checkbox]').attr("checked", "checked");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

Why do you find the [solutions](http://groups.google.com/group/jstree/browse_thread/thread/03cb646f2d3d1f0c) after you posted on SO and after hours of previous searching :)

```
*Check*:  
$.jstree._reference('#mytree').check_node('#id-of-node'); 

*Uncheck*:
$.jstree._reference('#mytree').uncheck_node('#id-of-node');

*Toggle check*:
$.jstree._reference('#mytree').change_state('#id-of-node');
```